# Why was this unit test declared failed?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

[image]

why does it say that 0 is not equal to 0 ?

Comment: Have you tried "0U" to make zero unsigned? The comparison uses the types the in your case 0 is signed and the count is unsigned.

Comment: @BrianWalker pretty sure that's right, just setting up an example here to test that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a casting issue. `count` returns an `NSUInteger` and `0` is being assumed to be an `NSInteger`.  Cast your zero to unsigned by writing `0U` or `(NSUInteger)0`.